# Post build event not working with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a solution that references multiple projects. In one of those referenced project I added the following Post-Event (to copy it's .exe file to the solution output).

```
xcopy /y "$(TargetName).*" "$(SolutionDir)UIBackendSSRSReports\$(OutDir)"
```

This works perfectly when compiling from Visual Studio, but when running from msbuild it fails (**exited with code 4**).

Seems like when using msbuild the values of OutDir (as well as the other macros) are different.

ex: $(OutDir)

```
In VS = D:\Workspace-ET\source_SSRSBackEnd\Common\BackEnd Automation\BackEndSSRSReports\UIBackendSSRSReports\bin\Debug
In msbuild =  " D:\B\1\Src_PMC-QA-Automation\BackEndSSRSReports_ssrsBranch\bin\
```

Not sure why they are so different, any ideas? We build with a buildAgent and buildController TFS setup

Comment: If you don't build the solution with msbuild, but projects directly, SolutionDir might be empty? Also you say OutDir is D:\B\1\Src_PMC\... but the xcopy's target is $(SolutionDir)UIBackendSSRSReports\$(OutDir) so that can never be a valid path?

Comment: When building from VS directly this is working the question is why it doesn't when building via msbuild? If I change the OuDir to match what msbuild gives then building in VS will fail. It seems to be one or the other but not both.

Comment: @ElieEl-Tawil what parameters do you pass to `msbuild`? most importantly: do you use it to build the solution or just the project? if you do `msbuild the.csproj` you'll get different results than `msbuild the.sln`

Comment: @MartinUllrich In the build definition I don't give any parameters and I build the .sln file. The Post-event that I added was for a project within that solution.